# how to merge git .diff file to source code?

Tags: linux, git, diff, patch

I export one diff file, use '`git diff HEAD^ HEAD > a.diff`' .
So, I wanna use a.diff file patch to another source code.
I use command '`patch -p0 < a.diff`', but it not works. said, "can't find files."
So, my question is: how to path a.diff file to source code?
Can someone help me solving this quesiont?
thanks a lot.

Comment: Just in case, are you sure your use case is not covered by `git cherry-pick`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `git` the diff output requires removing up to the first `/` in the path.  This should work:

```
patch -p1 < a.diff
```

Also try using `git format-patch` and `git am` (preserves logs if applying patch in another git directory):

```
rm -rf *.patch
git format-patch -1
git am *.patch
rm -rf *.patch
```

Comment: The `-p 1` command-line option to `patch` removes not a `/` character but rather a single (leftmost) path *component* from each pathname in the patch file, with component being a directory name, possibly coupled with a path separator.